# Javascript Multiple Inputs Value Output

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Hi I want to create a stamp script and I want the user to enter his name and address in three fields,
then he should see the fields later in the stamp edition?
I have 3 input fields where the user can give in his data,
now i will give this data in a new class. This is what i have:

```js
window.onload = function() {
$( "#Text1" )
  .keyup(function() {
    var value = $( this ).val();
    $( ".ausgabe" ).text( value );
  })
  .keyup();
};
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="Text1">
<input type="text" id="Text2">
<input type="text" id="Text3">
<div class="ausgabe"></div>
```

Comment: Where is `#eingabe` and `.ausgabe` in your HTML code?

Comment: Please explain clearly what is the problem,what is the input and what are your desired outputs??

Comment: Sorry palash its for a imprint script its for my customer

Comment: Now its right @palash

Comment: It's really not clear what you are trying to accomplish. If a User enters text in all three, do you want it to only show the value of one of the fields or all three? Should it be separated by anything? Do you want to do it the field is changed or every key press?

Comment: If we can't understand your question, Michael, we can't answer it. Can you please [edit] your question to explain what *exactly* you need help with? Where, in what element, will you "*give this data*"? In what format? If the user enters "Jennifer," "guppy" and "juvenile" in the inputs, in that order, what should the output be? What are you expecting the user to input? Numbers, strings?

Comment: @twisty vor i will create a imprint script and i will that this on keyup

Comment: yes  i can show you a img

Answer (score 0):

As you have not made it very clear what you are trying to accomplish, I am providing a simple example that might send you down the right path.

```js
$(function() {
  function updateDiv(source, target) {
    var newVal = "";
    source.each(function() {
      newVal += "<span class='text " + $(this).attr('id').replace("Text", "item-") + "'>" + $(this).val() + "</span> ";
    });
    target.html(newVal);
  }

  $("[id^='Text']").keyup(function(e) {
    updateDiv($("input[id^='Text']"), $(".ausgabe"));
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="Text1">
<input type="text" id="Text2">
<input type="text" id="Text3">
<div class="ausgabe"></div>
```

Since you already seem to understand `.html()` and .`text()`, we can look at the Selector. The one used will select all elements with an ID Attribute of `Text` in the beginning of the string. See More: https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/attribute-selectors/

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you want to mimic what the user is typing in the text inputs and show it in `ausgabe`. If that's what you want, then you can tie the `keyUp` event to each of the inputs.

```
$(input [type='text']).keyUp(function() {
   var value = $(this).val();
   $('.ausgabe').text(value);
}
```

But this will overwrite `.ausgabe` every time text is entered into a different input.

You could get the value of `.ausgabe` every time `keyUp` fires and pre-pend that value:

So you may want to have a button that renders each input's value into `.ausgabe`:

```
<button>.click(function() {
   $(input[type="text"]).each(function() {
      var boxText = $(this).val(); //text box value
      var aus = $('.ausgabe').text(); //ausgabe value
      $('.ausgabe').text(boxText + ' ' + aus); //combine the current text box value with ausgabe
   })
})
```

Comment: exactly this is what i want can i change the input type to a class or id

Comment: You can target whatever you want. Check out this guide on jQuery selectors: https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/.

Class: ```$('.<className>')```
ID: ```$('#<IdName>')```

Comment: @MichaelBurat can you mark this answer as correct please?